# How to download a parquet "file" (actually directory) using the Azure Client?

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-cli

I am using the `az storage fs file download` to download the contents for a `parquet` directory like this:

```
az storage fs file download 
   --path myname/1/batch-repo/form/Fulfillment/2022/01/02/batch-form-Fulfillment.parquet/  
   --account-name my-storage-account --f my-container
```

The download was attempted but apparently the `az cli` is not aware this is a parquet and can not handle it - either at the directory level or individual files:

> ValueError: This pipeline didn't have the RawDeserializer policy; can't deserialize

Is there any workaround to download the contents of a `parquet` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I received same error while downloading a directory using the same script as yours.

[image]

I can see that the individual files are getting downloaded with the below script.

```
az storage fs file download -f container --path dir1/part-00004-a9e77425-5fb4-456f-ba52-f821123bd193-c000.snappy.parquet --account-name <ACCOUNT_NAME> --account-key "<ACCOUNT_KEY>"
```

However, if you are trying to download at directory level you must use `az storage fs directory download`. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
az storage fs directory download -f container -d folder1 -s dir1 --account-name adls76224157 --account-name <ACCOUNT_NAME> --account-key "<ACCOUNT_KEY>"
```

#### Results:

[image]

Below is the structure of my files

[image]

Comment: Thx! Where is `folder1` in the path of your parquet files? It is not shown in the `Location`. In particular my "path" has about 8 subdirectory components .  It is unclear how to separate those subdirectories into the `folder` and `path` arguments shown in your example

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Apologies for the confusion, `dir1` is the source folder (i.e., the directory in my adls) and `folder1` is the local folder of CLI.